# How to select columns (across more panes) in Highcharts / Highstocks

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, multiple-conditions

I have this example: http://jsfiddle.net/qzprvohr/1/

What i'm trying to achieve - if i click (just once) to some column, i need to select all columns which has the same x-axis value. Currently it works just for clicked one, the rest is unselected. Also is there any possibility to use some background color for selected columns (not for column itself). Something like xAxis.crosshair.color & xAxis.crosshair.width do for hover state.

I tried something like this to select all columns (but it does not work properly):

```
plotOptions: {        
              series: {
                      allowPointSelect: true,
                      cursor: 'pointer',
                      point: {
                             events: {
                                    click: function (event)
                                    {
                                        var selectedCategory = this.category;
                                        var chart = this.series.chart;
                                        for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++)
                                        {
                                            for (var j = 0; j < chart.series[i].data.length; j++)
                                            {
                                                if (typeof chart.series[i].data[j] !== "undefined" &&
                                                    chart.series[i].data[j].category == selectedCategory)
                                                {
                                                    chart.series[i].data[j].select(true, true);

                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played a bit with the example and i think i found the solution. If I use **setTimeout** function for selection then all selected column will stay in selected state. Also i used plotBands for another background color. Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/qzprvohr/2/

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function (event) {
                            var clickedPoint = this;
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                var selectedCategory = clickedPoint.category;
                                var chart = clickedPoint.series.chart;
                                for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
                                    for (var j = 0; j < chart.series[i].data.length; j++) {
                                        if (typeof chart.series[i].data[j] !== "undefined" &&                                                       chart.series[i].data[j].category == selectedCategory) {
                                            chart.series[i].data[j].select(true, true);
                                            chart.xAxis[i].removePlotBand('selection' + i)
                                            chart.xAxis[i].addPlotBand({
                                                color:'red',
                                                from: selectedCategory - 40000000,
                                                to: selectedCategory + 40000000,
                                                id: 'selection'+i
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```